# how to get response of rest webservice on the same page in jsp on click of anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, rest

I have a jsp page where i am checking that is there any records in database.If yes then i am displaying them and if not then I am calling the rest webservice and then I am getting response of the service on a browser generated window. But I want to give some link on the page where the response is generated. So how could I give that as I don't have the page URL where the response is generating.Here is my code.

RestConroller-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/invoke/healthcheck", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseModel doHealthCheck(){
        ResponseModel response = null;
        HEALTHCHECK hcObj = null;
        ArrayList stausList = null;
        try {
            response = new ResponseModel();
            hcObj= new HEALTHCHECK();
            stausList = hcObj.checkPrerequisits();
            response.setData(stausList);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception in getting healthCheckStatus : "+e);
        }
        return response;
    }
```

JSP-

```
<body>

    <form action="healthcheck.jsp" method="GET" id="healthCheckform">
        <h3 align="center">HealthCheck Details</h3>

        <%
            HEALTHCHECK obj = new HEALTHCHECK();
            HEALTHCHECK healthCheck = new HEALTHCHECK();
            ArrayList<HashMap> statusList = healthCheck
                    .selectHealthCheckDetails();
            if (statusList.size() == 0) {
        %>

    <div>
            <a href="dataAnalytics/invoke/healthcheck" target="_Self" id="a" >Click
            Here </a> for initiating health check details
        </div>


        <%
            } else {
......
}
```